# Who will inhabit the earth after judgement day?

Tags: day-of-judgement

After judgement day the wrongdoers go to hell and the ones who pleased Allah go to heaven, but my question is that:

What will happen with the earth?

Answer (score 4):

At the judgment day and before just after the Horn is blown everything in Earth will be destroyed and flushed, and there is plenty of Ayat talking about that. 
Indeed The last part (Juzeh) all of it talks about that day.

Some of the states that ALLAH talk about:

> [And the mountains are removed and will be [but] a mirage.](http://quran.com/78/20)

[Surat At-Takwīr (The Overthrowing) - سورة التكوير](http://quran.com/81)

[Surat Al-'Infiţār (The Cleaving) - سورة الإنفطار](http://quran.com/82)

[Surat Al-'Inshiqāq (The Sundering) - سورة الإنشقاق](http://quran.com/84)

And many other Surat and Ayat talks about that day.

But back to your question. You ask what happen after that day...

Will the Earth be part of the heaven or part of the hell!!! this is the point to talk about.

Some says that it will be a part of the Heaven and they prove with the Aya

> سَابِقُوا إِلَىٰ مَغْفِرَةٍ مِّن رَّبِّكُمْ وَجَنَّةٍ عَرْضُهَا
>   كَعَرْضِ السَّمَاءِ وَالْأَرْضِ أُعِدَّتْ لِلَّذِينَ آمَنُوا بِاللَّهِ
>   وَرُسُلِهِ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ فَضْلُ اللَّهِ يُؤْتِيهِ مَن يَشَاءُ ۚ وَاللَّهُ
>   ذُو الْفَضْلِ الْعَظِيمِ
>
> Race toward forgiveness from your Lord and a Garden whose width is
>   like the width of the heavens and earth, prepared for those who
>   believed in Allah and His messengers. That is the bounty of Allah
>   which He gives to whom He wills, and Allah is the possessor of great
>   bounty.[57/21](http://quran.com/57/21)

And they claim that the heaven is already founded but is unseen by us.

While others say this Aya is just an example to show how wide will be and it doesn't indicate the real state of Earth.

So this is just explanations and nobody really knows what it will be after the judgment day.

Answer (score 3):

Everything will be destroyed at the judgement day, everyone is revived from the death.

As Allah says in surat Al Qariah:

> And the mountains will be like wool, fluffed up.
>   [101:5](http://quran.com/101/5)

And in surah Al-takwir:

> When the sun is wrapped up [in darkness]
>    And when the stars fall, dispersing,
>    And when the mountains are removed
>    And when full-term she-camels are neglected
>   [...]
>    And when the sky is stripped away
>   [81](http://quran.com/81)

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad Ibn Muslim narrated from Imam Baqir (a.s.):

> From when Allah created earth, created seven world of humans that they
>   were not children of Adam. He created them from earth and they settled
>   in earth after each other and they extincted. then he created Adam the
>   father of current peoples. by Allah paradise never has been empty from
>   soul of believers and hell has been never empty from soul of Kafirs
>   and evil people. Perhaps you think when Allah send people to paradise
>   and hell then he will not be worshiped in cities?! And will not create
>   the people who pray him? This is not true. By God he will have
>   creation without male and female and they will worship him. He will
>   create a new earth that carry them and will create a sky that people
>   live under its shade. Do not you see Quran says: **[It will be] on the
>   Day the earth will be replaced by another earth, and the heavens [as
>   well], and all creatures will come out before Allah, the One, the
>   Prevailing** ([14:48](http://tanzil.net/#14:48)). This verse means at that day earth will be
>   changed to a new earth and skies will change to another skies. And he
>   says: **Did We fail in the first creation? But they are in confusion
>   over a new creation** ([50:15](http://tanzil.net/#50:15)).

According to this hadith a new earth with new kind of humans will be created and they will worship God.

**Reference**:

[www.andisheqom.com](http://www.andisheqom.com/Files/faq.php?level=4&id=4933&urlId=2156)

Answer (score -2):

The Earth will be destroyed. 
Everything that was built will be destroyed except Jannah (paradise) and Jahannam (hell).

Comment: Please consider given some references to your statement!